# By pass UI TestCases in Swift for some cases

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest, uitest

I'm implementing `UITestCases` in iOS , but i facing issues while implementing permission. for some operation.
Only authorised people allowed to enter in some section of the app, If alert opens then we need to skip the `UITestCases` for next page and jump to other `UITestCases`.
Please check the screenshot of app .

[image]

```
  app.buttons["Fill out"].tap()
```

After this code , i need to check if Alert is visible then press on dismiss button and skip the below code

```
let textViewsQuery = app/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.textViews/*[[".scrollViews.textViews",".textViews"],[[[-1,1],[-1,0]]],[0]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/
            textViewsQuery.otherElements["4. Test App"].doubleTap()
            let textView = app.scrollViews.children(matching: .textView).element
            textView.swipeDown()
            textView.children(matching: .textView).element(boundBy: 0).tap()
            app.navigationBars["Fill Out"].buttons["Back"].tap()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an interruption monitor that checks for such alerts.

```swift
 app.launch()
  addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "Permission Dialog") {
    (alert) -> Bool in
    alert.buttons["dismiss"].tap()
    return true
  }
  app.tap()
```

Comment: Use `XCTSkipIf(_:_:file:line:)` with the above interruption monitor to skip the test case with valid reason.